# Symfony 2.0 - How to create route with array-parameters?

Tags: routes, symfony

I want to create a route, that matches on an array.

example:

```
    Name_show:
        pattern:  /Name/{names}
        defaults: { _controller: testBundle:Name:showNames }
```

where `{names}` holds an array of names, like:

`array([1] => 'Thomas', [2] => 'Anton', [3] => 'Berta');`

How to handle this? Symfony 2.0 responses with

`Warning: preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given`

can't find any solution in symfony doc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use it as a string and just `serialize()` the content before and after.

As far as I know symfony2 doesn't allow arrays in routing, how would the URL Look with an array in? A URL has to be a string, so serializing the array and passing it as a string is probably a better option.

Comment: An URL with an array will look like this: `http://domain.com?array[]=lorem&array[]=ipsum`

Comment: @user2019515 true, but I'm not sure that symfony2 allows that

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @JamesHalsall about serializing.  I would also add that the serialized string should then be urlencoded before being used as a GET parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You have to validate the route, so either use some contrived event handling (see the [kernel.controller event](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/internals.html#kernel-controller-event) ) or use a controller that simply redirects to a new URL if the Name is in the array or displays an error page.

Also you could experiment with the [ChainRouter](https://github.com/symfony-cmf/ChainRoutingBundle) that is a replacement for the default Symfony2 router (supports Doctrine-based routing and such).