# Dynamically changing route string inside the controller

Tags: php, symfony

I create urls using the following pattern:

```
www.website.com/page/1/sort/login
```

When I wanna change, for example, sorting method, I simply add the new one to the end of the url:

```
www.website.com/page/1/sort/login/sort/email
```

And replace the old one in the controller (string replaces etc...). So, clicking the link with URL from above would:

1. Redirect to `www.website.com/page/1/sort/login/sort/email`
2. Replace sorting by login with sorting by email IN CONTROLLER

The problem is that the link doesn't change of course - it contains double sort elements.

---

What I want to achieve is to change the route in the URL from controller's method after the redirect. Is this possible?

Comment: Isn't it easier to make a function sort() that behaves differently depending on the parameter that you send to it ? So in your controller you should have a function sort ( $sort_parameter ) { //Do stuff  }

Then you could change the url, to www.website.com/page/1/sort/SORT_PARAMETER

Just load the uri helper, and extract the variable from the URL

Comment: Sort was just an example - I have a lot of different parameters here. So it could be like www.localhost.com/page/1/sort/login/order/asc/active/true...where the whole string after .com is one get parameter.

Comment: And when I add new parameter, I just add it to the end of the URL in twig, and then replace it correctly in the controller.

Comment: Seems to me that you have a function that is working with a "big" number of parameters.  Try passing an array of parameters, with $this->uri->uri_to_assoc(n).  Here's the documentation: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/uri.html      

Then just get the proper values and your funcyion will be working like a charm ;]

Comment: @wick3d This is Symfony, not CodeIgniter. Can you please post the content of your controller and route definition? How are you processing this query?

Comment: @Touki Aw balls! Sorry mate I completely thought this was CI. Can't really help you with Symphony, but after a short research I found this little question here on stackoverflow regarding how to pass an array in the url - might lead you in the right direction.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20050460/symfony-generate-url-with-parameter-in-controller

and this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8354634/symfony-2-0-how-to-create-route-with-array-parameters